# How to rewrite URL using NGINX to hide index.php inside multiple subfolders that change frequently?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

So we have a PHP development server where each dev has a personal subdomain like https://dev-abc.mysite.com with a corresponding NGINX config.

Devs check out a branch of our repo into folders like this:

- /var/www/html/dev-abc/branch-X
- /var/www/html/dev-abc/branch-Y
- /var/www/html/dev-abc/branch-Z

**URL pattern:**
[https://dev-abc.mysite.com/{BRANCH}/index.php/{MODULE}/{CLASS}/?event={EVENT}&otherParamX=Y](https://dev-abc.mysite.com/%7BBRANCH%7D/index.php/%7BMODULE%7D/%7BCLASS%7D/?event=%7BEVENT%7D&otherParamX=Y)

{MODULE} is a folder in modules/
{CLASS} is a class file in modules/{MODULE}
{EVENT} is a method inside a class inside modules/{MODULE}

Branches are accessed like so:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/index.php/report/invoice

We are simply trying to rewrite the URL to:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/invoice/

For all subdirectories under their subdomain.

The NGINX configs look like this:

**Path:**
/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev-abc.conf

```
server {
        server_tokens off;

        listen 80;
        autoindex off;
        server_name dev-abc.mysite.com;
        root /var/www/html/dev-a;

        error_log /home/dev-abc/nginx-error.log notice;

        include /etc/nginx/includes/dev_sandbox;

        rewrite_log on;
}
```

*Note: /etc/nginx/includes/dev_sandbox includes a lot of stuff for headers and CORS so I won't post it unless it's needed because it's long.*

I have tried the following:

**Attempt 1:**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

NGINX throws: ^(.+.php)(/.+)" does not match "/index.php"
Also getting "File not found" in the browser

**Attempt 2:**

```
location ~(.+)/(.+) {
    try_files $uri $1/index.php/$2;
}
```

Works:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/

Does not work:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/invoice/

**Attempt 3:**

```
location ~(.+)/(.+)/(.+) {
    try_files $uri $1/control.php/$2/$3;
}
```

Works:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/invoice/

Does not work:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/

Throws:
"/var/www/html/dev-abc/branch-X/report/index.php" is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repetition operators like `*` and `+` are [greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). So the first capture in `(.+)/(.+)` takes everything until the **last** `/` (with at least one character following it). So the behaviour of your *Attempt 2* is entirely expected.

You can use the lazy repetition operators instead, like `*?` and `+?`, for example:

```
location ~ (.+?)/(.+) { ... }
```

Or you can use a character class that matches only characters which are not `/` (remembering that the first character is always a `/`), for example:

```
location ~ (/[^/]+)/(.+) { ... }
```

Although not strictly necessary in this case, but you should probably add [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) around the expression as you are only interested in matching the entire URI, for example:

```
location ~ ^(.+?)/(.+)$ { ... }
```

Or:

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)/(.+)$ { ... }
```

---

**Important Note**

Regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found. Make sure that your `location ^(.+.php)(/.+)` block appears first in the order, to avoid a redirection loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this but same result as attempt #2 above  


`    location ~ ^(/[^/]+)/(.+)$ {
            try_files $uri $1/index.php/$2/$3;
        }`

Works:  
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/

Does not work:  
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/invoice/

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
location ~ ^(.+?)\/(.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $1/index.php/$2;
}
```

Works:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/invoice/
-> https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/index.php/report/invoice/

Works:
https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/report/
-> https://dev-abc.mysite.com/branch-X/index.php/report/